# WSS 2007 - SaveProperties=true?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I've got a really weird issue.

I'm updating an already existing webpartpage using SPLimitedWebPartManager.
I'm adding my webpart and do all Update. (EDIT : The updates are done from a console application).

The weird behaviour is no users can view the webpages. Only the administrator can see them, BUT when the admin have load the page once, then, all users can see the webpage using their own rights...

Of course, all users have read access to it.

The log message when the user have his access denied is "

```
11/03/2011 10:32:07.11 w3wp.exe (0x08D8) 0x120C Windows SharePoint Services     Web Parts 7047 Information ###SERVER_URL###/Projects/Basket/Basket.aspx - ###NAMESPACE###.Basket.WebPartBasket, #NAMESPACE#, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###PUBLICTOKEN###. Impossible de définir SaveProperties=true sur GET. Le thread a été abandonné.
```

In english : "Failed to set SaveProperties=true on GET. Thread aborted."

Any idea ??

Thanks a lot,

Yoann

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to security restrictions that you cannot update items or other things to the database with a GET request.

You must:

1. Set [SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allowunsafeupdates.aspx) to true
2. Call Update on whatever you are updating
3. Set SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates to false

But before you do this, think about: what will happen if my user refreshes page for multiple times?

Comment: It's happen after an update from a console application, so when i'm doing the update, the AllowUnsafeUpdates always is to true. But it seems than the Producer/Consumer Connection between webparts is serialized during the first render....